# How to use regex to indent code in notepad++

Tags: regex

for example I have the following code

```
Module MPI
    Use MPI
    !
! MPI info
    If (true) Then
        Print *, ''
! empty line 1
! empty line 2
    End If
    Integer ithread, nthread, ierr
End Module MPI
```

The lines start with `!` sign which is comment lines in fortran. **I want those comment lines have the same indent as their previous line indent.**

That is I want this format

```
Module MPI
    Use MPI
    !
    ! MPI info
    If (true) Then
        Print *, ''
        ! empty line 1
        ! empty line 2
    End If
    Integer ithread, nthread, ierr
End Module MPI
```

I want to do this in notepad++ using regex. But if there are better choice feel free to answer.

Here is what I have tried: replace `^(\s*)(.*?\r\n)\s*\!` as `$1$2$1!`. However it produce

```
Module MPI
    Use MPI
    !
! MPI info
    If (true) Then
        Print *, ''
        ! empty line 1
! empty line 2
    End If
    Integer ithread, nthread, ierr
End Module MPI
```

There is still two lines not right. It seems that though the pattern `^(\s*)(.*?\r\n)\s*\!` matches this line, however, it just skip it for the regex engine already matched previous lines.

**My question is how to solve this indent problem with regex?**

Comment: This looks like a job for a parser.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My question is actually a post processing of the result generated by universalindentGUI

Comment: It is allowed to use the same regex more times? For example, you have at most 3 consecutive comment lines, so you will click on the "replace all" button 3 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the search text `^( +)(.*\R)(!)` and the replace text `\1\2\1\3` then clicking on "Replace all" twice does what is wanted on the sample text. I cannot see a way of doing this in one pass.

The expression looks for a line with leading spaces followed by a line starting with a `!`. The capture groups are the leading spaces in `\1`, the rest of that line including the newline in `\2` and the leading `!` in `\3`. The replacement just assembles the captures in the right order. Note that you could omit the capture group around the `!` and just have an explicit `! in the replacement, but I like to use captures in such contexts as they often allow for shorter replacements (although not in this case) and easier enhancements.

Answer (score 1):

Since the engine is already passed on a comment line to indent it, I think it is impossible to use the same entire **edited** line for the next match to get the number of spaces. So I think you have to repeat the same replacement more times. Try with:

```
^(\s*)([^!\s].*?\r\n(\1\!.*?\r\n)*)\s*\!
```

always replacing it with `$1$2$1!`.

Like I said in the comment, if you have at most N consecutive comment lines, you will click on the "replace all" button N times