# Cross-line regex match in a Perl one-liner

Tags: regex, perl

My question sounds trivial, but I google many page still can't not find an answer.

I am on Windows. I have a text file. If I open it with Notepad++, it looks like this

[image]

I want to try several things

1. delete all carriage return and line feed

   `perl -i.bak -pe "s/\r\n//g" a.txt`

surprisingly, there is nothing changed. What is wrong? But according to the [doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), I am pretty sure `\r` is `CR` and `\n` is `LF`

2. What I actually want to do is match across line. for example `^function.*\r\n!` will match just like Notepad++ will does

[image]

If we want to indent the ! line if its previous line is started with "function", a naive thought would be (actually it works is notepad++)

```
perl -i.bak -pe "s/^(function.*\r\n)!/$1\t!/g" a.txt
```

But it didn't work. How to do it correctly?

Comment: please try this: `perl -i.bak -pe "s/^(.*\r\n)!/$1\t!/sg" a.txt` or else `perl -i.bak -pe "s/\s*$//sg" a.txt`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166976/removing-crlf-0d-0a-from-string-in-perl

Comment: @ssr1012, That's of no use. It's about merging all lines into one, and it's for a different OS.

Comment: @ikegami It is just an example to demonstrate feature I want . Anyway, merging lines is very useful : )

Comment: `od -c a.txt | less` to see what characters you really have in your file.

Comment: @xxfelixxx Hey, guys, I already screen captured the notepad++ view, it clearly shows the CR and LF.

Comment: Try `perl -i.bak -pe "s/\\R+//g" a.txt`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi, WiktorStribiżew, thanks. \R works. But it still doesn't explain why apparent \r\n failed. Also `\R!` seems can't match across the line

Comment: The [`\R` can match across lines](https://regex101.com/r/tT8zK9/2) since `\R` matches any linebreak sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `perl -i.bak -pe "s/\n//" a.txt`

I.e. just change `\r\n` to `\n` for the `\r\n` is automatically converted to `\n` on Windows as it was explained by ikegami.

---

2. `perl -i.bak -0777 -pe "s/^(function.*?\n)!/\1\t!/gm" a.txt`

The main point here is that you need to read the entire file contents into a single string in order to do cross-line matches. `-0777` parameter instructs Perl to do so (alternatively you may set `$/` to an empty string from within Perl script).

Comment: Hi, Dmitry Egorov. Currently, your answer works. And `m` seems not needed here. However, why things got so complicated, I just switch to perl because sed is so awkward in regex, while perl is also awkward in something. : )

Comment: @user15964, yes, you're right. Corrected the answer.

Comment: I would also like to thank @LukStorms for the simpler regex

Comment: `-0777` can be used instead of `BEGIN{undef $/;}`

Comment: @ikegami Hi, ikegami. You deleted your answer? That is a good reference too.

Comment: It didn't do what you asked. (I stopped reading too soon. I wasn't planning on answering at all, since I'm too tired, but so much bad misinformation was being posted.)

Comment: @ikegami There is one thing I doubt. `BEGIN{undef $/;}` seems like something advanced, does it? Sorry, I am new to perl, so I don't know. Is there any simpler way?

Comment: -0015 will probably be a bit more efficient. Since 015 is the octal value for the carriage return.

Comment: @LukStorms, I'm not sure -0015 is more efficient than -0777 since it will cause Perl to search the input file for 015, I think (yet, it's only my guess -- this needs to be checked). Since all \015\012 are replaced with \012 on Windows, we effectively end up with slurping the entire file into a single string. -0000 would basically do the same in our case. On the other hand, -0777 instructs Perl to slurp the entire file explicitly without searching contents for any line delimiters, so the I expect the latter to be a little bit more effective, provided my guess is correct.

Comment: I agree on that it's not sure. It might depends on the size of the file. Most of the time the -0777 will probably be faster. But on big files it'll use less memory when perl processes the file line by line. So when I said it would be more efficient I was thinking about the memory usage.

Comment: @LukStorms, now I see your point. Yes, generally it may prove more efficient to process large files line by line, but in this particular case the entire content needs to be searched to do cross-line match, so we have to have the whole file in-memory at some points. Of course, we may elaborate the algorithm further to address this potential memory usage issue, but this would make the one-liner more complex and therefore I personally would do that only if such large files are definitely in our scope.

Answer (score 3):

By default, on Windows, CR+LF gets transformed to LF on read, and LF gets transformed to CR+LF on write. This makes lines look like they're LF-terminated regardless of the OS.

---

If sounds like you want to add a leading tab to lines starting with `!`.

```
perl -i.bak -pe"s/^!/\t!/" a.txt
   -or-
perl -i.bak -pe"s/^(?=!)/\t/" a.txt
```

You might also be trying to avoid doing it on the first line.

```
perl -i.bak -pe"s/^!/\t!/ if $. > 1" a.txt
   -or-
perl -i.bak -pe"s/^(?=!)/\t/ if $. > 1" a.txt
```

Comment: ikegami, I am very sorry for my post which is not clear enough and may already wasted you a lot of time. Well, as I said in the post, I insisted to do it across line for a reason. What I actually want to do is indent the ! line according to the previous line, for example only indent ! line when its previous line is start with "function". My post actually has the same goal as my previous post "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38452288/how-to-use-regex-to-indent-code-in-notepad". If you have any better idea using perl, feel free to add an answer, just neglect notepad++ tag.

Comment: The current solution doesn't do it just for the lines with a '!' that have a 'function' on the previous line.